# REST API Best practices. List data using different endpoint

Tags: rest

I have a situation where I have 2 entities. `Tenant` and `Order`. Each order belongs to a `Tenant`. For practical reasons i want to express that order belongs to tenant so the uri for order would be

```
/Tenants/<tenantId>/Orders/<orderId>
```

However we have this concept that you have access to multiple tenants and i would like to list ALL orders from all tenants i have access to (via som bearer token). Also i would like to apply some filtering sorting etc on this.

What i was wondering

1. New endpoint for query only `/Orders`
2. Custom method `/Tenants:ListOrders`
3. Wldcard `/Tenants/-/Orders`
4. Something else?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

Therefore, your proposed alternatives are all *fine*.

The resource identifier is, in a sense, the "name" of the representation returned when you GET the resource.  But, just as with variable in your code, the name can be anything that makes sense.

```
/that-new-orders-report-that-bob-wanted
```

Using a shared hierarchy of path segments can be convenient when you want to use relative resolution to compute one resource identifier from another.